# Flask-SQLAlchemy wont create tables and Foreign Key

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a model that wont create the table in the database as shown below

class Person(db.Model):

```
__tablename__ = 'persons'

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
name = db.Column(db.String(20))
pets = db.relationship('Pet', backref='person')
```

class Pet(db.Model):

```
__tablename__ = 'pets'

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
name=db.Column(db.String(20))
owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('person.id'),nullable=False)
```

Might the issue be because the class name and the table name do not match since using the command

```
db.create_all()
```

throws an error??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('person.id'),nullable=False)
```

to

```
owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('persons.id'),nullable=False)
```

since your table is persons

And give this relationship a different name since you already have a table called pets

```
pets = db.relationship('Pet', backref='person')
```

you could for example do this

```
persons_pets = db.relationship('Pet', backref='person')
```